# '+' can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

I've hit upon a 'can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)' error and whilst it seems simple enough I'm unsure about how to get around it. I thought my logic was sound - convert the entered string variable to an integer and then carry out the basic operation - but apparently I'm missing some key bit of information.

```
puts 'What is your favourite number?'
favenum = gets.chomp
better = favenum.to_i + 1
puts 'Yeah '+favenum+' is nice enough but '+better+' is bigger and better by far! Think on.'
```

Have tried searching for an answer but examples of the same error out there are way beyond my rudimentary ruby skills at present.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ruby (unlike some other languages) does not cast objects to strings when they are operands in `String#+` method. Either cast to string manually:

```
puts 'Yeah ' + favenum.to_s + ' is nice enough but ' + better.to_s + ' is bigger and better by far!'
```

or use string interpolation (note the double quotes):

```
puts "Yeah #{favenum} is nice enough but #{better} is bigger and better by far!"
```

Comment: So the error in my code is in the output of the variables, not in the manipulation of them in the lines above? Am I correct in thinking favenum is originally stored as a string? Maybe the tutorial I'm following (http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/?Chapter=04) isn't all it's cracked up to be...?

Comment: @DanSolo: Indeed, `favenum` indeed is a string and shouldn't cause the error. It's integer `better` variable that causes it.

Comment: Great, thanks. Now you mention it I can see logically why using' + better +' when better is an integer would cause an error. Thanks for the alternative options in getting around it. My journey continues...

Answer (score 5):

Try using string interpolation, like this:

```
puts "Yeah #{favenum} is nice enough but #{better} is bigger and better by far! Think on."
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the tutorial you're following

```
puts 'Please enter your favourite number: '
number = gets.chomp
imp = number.to_i + 1
puts 'I\'d say '.to_s + imp.to_s + ' is a much better number.'
```

Produces the "correct" result at a beginner level.